# Why does this exception appears when reading a file, but not when storing in it?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm currently working on a project with MFC and I noticed something weird that apparently has been there for a couple of years. When I launch the .exe of the program, it will do n number of things including reading a .DAT file and storing it as well. If the file doesn't exists, the program will try to find it with no luck throwing this CFile exception: The file could not be located. Which is correct because it doesn't exists. I have to do some operations first to generate that file, the storing process works fine. When the file exists and I run the program again, it's supposed read the file but this CArchive exception shows up: Invalid file format. And I don't understand why.

This is the Serialize():

```
//Fruits.cpp

void CFruits::Serialize(CArchive &ar)
{
    int nVersion = 0;
    CObject::Serialize(ar);
    ar.SerializeClass(GetRuntimeClass());

    if(ar.IsStoring())
    {
        ar.Write(&m_bInit,sizeof(bool));            
        ar.Write(&m_bYummy,sizeof(bool));
        ar.Write(&m_bAcid, sizeof(bool));   
        ar.Write(&m_bFresh,sizeof(bool));
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ar<<m_cType;    
        ar<<m_cColour;
        ar<<m_cFlavor;  
        ar<<m_cPrice;   
        ar<<m_cQuantity;
    }
    else
    {
        nVersion = ar.GetObjectSchema();
        ar.Read(&m_bInit,sizeof(bool));     
        ar.Read(&m_bYummy,sizeof(bool));
        ar.Read(&m_bAcid, sizeof(bool));    
        ar.Read(&m_bFresh,sizeof(bool));    
        ...
        ...
        ...

        if( nVersion >= 2 || nVersion < 0)
            ar<<m_cType;
        else
            m_cType=0;

        if (nVersion >= 3 || nVersion < 0)
            ar<<m_cColour;
        else
            m_cColour=0;

        if (nVersion >= 4 || nVersion < 0)
            ar<<m_cFlavor;  
        else
            ar<<m_cFlavor=0;

        if( nVersion >= 5 || nVersion < 0)
        {
            ar<<m_cPrice;   
            ar<<m_cQuantity;
        }
        else
        {
            m_cPrice=0; 
            m_cQuantity=0;
        }            
    }

    m_oSales.Serialize(ar);     
    m_oAdmin.Serialize(ar);     
    ...
    ...     
}

IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(CVehiculo,CObject,VERSIONABLE_SCHEMA | 6)
```

This is the SerializeElements:

```
//Fruits.cpp

void AFXAPI SerializeElements(CArchive &ar,CFruits * fruits,int ncount)
{
    try
    {
        for(cont=0;cont<ncount;cont++)
            fruits[cont].Serialize(ar);

    }
    catch(CArchiveException *AE)
    {
        //Here it stores the exception in a Log. Exception 5
    }
}
```

The serializeElements is used to store and read the file n times, as declared here in the header file of fruits:

```
//Fruits.h

class CFruits : public CObject
{
public:
    CFruits();
    CFruits(const CFruits &O);
    virtual ~CFruits();
    void operator = (const CFruits &O);
    void        Serialize(CArchive &ar);

protected:
    DECLARE_SERIAL(CFruits)
};

void AFXAPI SerializeElements(CArchive &ar,CFruits * fruits,int ncount);

typedef CArray<CFruits, CFruitso&> TArrayFruits;
```

The values of this Array, and the methods used to call the serialize are defined here in my main function:

```
//main.h

#include "CFruits.h"

class CMain : public CDialog 
{
// Construction
public:

    enum T_Fruits { eFruitsOnLine, eFruitsIng, eFruitsTra, eFruitsAnt, eFruitsP3, eFruitsP2, eFruitsP1, eFruitsC1, eFruitsC0, eFruitsEscape, eFruitsVideo};

private:

    void            StoreFruits();
    void            ReadFruits();
```

The SerializeElements for-loop is supposed to run 11 times, but I noticed that it only does it 1 time, then the Schema version changes to -1, (originally 6 cause I managed to trace the value). This happens only when reading the file.
I've tried the following:
I can't use debug so I have to use Logs, I placed a Log after every sentence in the Serialize() function, I found what seems to be the issue, this line:

`ar.SerializeClass(GetRuntimeClass());`

I used a try-catch and found that when that sentence happens, it throws the exception so, it doesn't continue reading. That is the moment where the version changes to -1. I tried to change that to:

`ar.SerializeClass(RUNTIME_CLASS(CFruits));`

Is the same result, I've read many forums trying to find the answer but I can't seem to do so. I've read the documentation and I found this here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/carchive-class?view=vs-2019#serializeclass

> Like ReadClass, SerializeClass verifies that the archived class
> information is compatible with your runtime class. If it is not
> compatible, SerializeClass will throw a CArchiveException.

But it doesn't make sense to me, because it doesn't fail storing. Should I look into something else?

Thank you

EDIT:
I'm posting the Store and Read methods

```
void CMain::ReadFruits()
{
    CString CSerror, sFileName;
    CString sDebug;
                
    try
    {
        sFileName.Format("FRUITS%03d.DAT",GetNumT());
        CFile fFruitsTag(sFileName,CFile::modeRead);
        CArchive ar(&fFruitsTag,CArchive::load);
        m_vFruits.Serialize(ar);
        ar.Close();
        fFruitsTag.Close();
    }
    catch(CFileException *FE)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch(CArchiveException *AE)
    {
        ...
    }
}

void CMain::StoreFruits()
{
    CString CSerror, sFileName;

    try
    {
        if(!m_bStoringFruits)
        {
            sFileName.Format("FRUITS%03d.DAT",GetNumT());
            m_bStoringFruits=true;
            CFile fFruitsTag(sFileName,CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite);
            CArchive ar(&fFruitsTag,CArchive::store);
            m_vFruits.Serialize(ar);
            ar.Close();
            fFruitsTag.Close();
            m_bStoringFruits=false;
        }
    }
    catch(CFileException *FE)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch(CArchiveException *AE)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch(CException *e)
    {       
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, and I've been doing MFC a really long time, SerializeClass is an MFC implementation detail. You don't need to call it. (It's there I think for the  operator<<() and operator>>() of MFC classes, IIRC). You also don't need to call CObject::Serialize() because it doesn't do anything ( there is no code in the implementation).

Comment: In my attempts of finding the problem, I deleted that line `CObject::Serialize()`, and, as you said it doesn't do anything relevant or changes anything so I leave it there. I'll edit the question to add the read and store methods

Comment: That code *never* worked as intended. For one, you are writing to the `CArchive` both when writing a file and *reading* from it. Start with [Serialization in MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/serialization-in-mfc) to learn, how this is supposed to work. And, as always, the real information is in the Technical Notes ([TN002: Persistent Object Data Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn002-persistent-object-data-format)).

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for the information, I found something really interesting: "Any object that is serialized with a direct call to Serialize must not use CArchive::GetObjectSchema or must handle a return value of (UINT)-1 indicating that the version was unknown."..."Because Serialize is called directly on your document, it is not usually possible for the sub-objects of the document to archive references to their parent document." I think this matches with my case, also what you said makes sense, I'll look into it. Many many thanks